# VLOOKUP and insert a specific value

Tags: excel

i have two sheets in excel 2007 and i want to search if the value in sheet1 A1 exists in sheet2 array B then insert in sheet1 C1 the value of the specific cell A that the value was found.

ex. if the value of sheet1!A1 was found in the sheet2!B7 then insert the value sheet2!A7 in cell sheet1!C1.

=IF(ISNA(VLOOKUP(Sheet1!A1;Sheet2!B1:B999;1;FALSE));"Not Found";<>)

thank you

Comment: Welcome to StackOverflow! What is the question here? If you don't state a clear question, people might miss your point and your question might get closed. You may edit your question to clarify it.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

For a "left lookup" you need INDEX/ MATCH

`=IFERROR(INDEX(Sheet2!A$1:A$999;MATCH(Sheet1!A1;Sheet2!B$1:B$999;0));"Not Found")`

Comment: thank you veery much ! that was exaclty what i was looking .